# How can I use settings stored with Xam.plugins.settings in my XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, plugins, xamarin.forms, settings

**Thanks** to *James Montemagno* for this plugin.[https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin ]

I have used it in my c# code easily: `CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("abc", "")`
But I also want to use those settings in my XAML.

Before this plugin, I was using my own basic (inefficient) array setup and used: ...`Text="{x:Static local:Settings.abc}"`... Now I have completely converted over to this plugin. And it works well in c#, but am struggling to get it working in XAML.

I Tried `{x:Static local:Helpers.Settings.GeneralSettings.abc}`, and `{x:Static helps:Settings.GeneralSettings.abc}` (creating xmlns:help).

**How can I use those settings in my XAML code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to set up a Property Accessor (get/set) - and bind the control to that method.

As a quick (one way) example..

*Page Code behind*

```
public int MyNumber
{
    //This may be different, depending on what your Settings class has been named and where its reference has been stored - but it is the same plugin.
    return App.Settings.GetValueOrDefault("myNumber",0);
}
```

*XAML*

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyNumber}"/>
```

You'll also want to make sure you've set the `BindingContext`.  I find it easiest to do this after `InitializeComponent();` in the page constructor, simply by using `BindingContext = this;`.

A more complex implementation (With two way data binding) can be found in the [Settings Plugin Documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin/DataBindingToSettings.html).